# RenderScript wrongly manipulating output of kernel

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

I'm trying to use Android's RenderScript to render a semi-transparent circle behind an image, but things go very wrong when returning a value from the RenderScript kernel.

This is my kernel:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(be.abyx.aurora)
// We don't need very high precision floating points
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

// Center position of the circle
int centerX = 0;
int centerY = 0;

// Radius of the circle
int radius = 0;

// Destination colour of the background can be set here.
float destinationR;
float destinationG;
float destinationB;
float destinationA;

static int square(int input) {
    return input * input;
}

uchar4 RS_KERNEL circleRender(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    //Convert input uchar4 to float4
    float4 f4 = rsUnpackColor8888(in);

    // Check if the current coordinates fall inside the circle
    if (square(x - centerX) + square(y - centerY) < square(radius)) {
        // Check if current position is transparent, we then need to add the background!)
        if (f4.a == 0) {
            uchar4 temp = rsPackColorTo8888(0.686f, 0.686f, 0.686f, 0.561f);
            return temp;
        }
    }

    return rsPackColorTo8888(f4);
}
```

Now, the `rsPackColorTo8888()` function takes 4 floats with a value between 0.0 and 1.0. The resulting ARGB-color is then found by calculating 255 times each float value. So the given floats correspond to the color R = 0.686 * 255 = 175, G = 0.686 * 255 = 175, B = 0.686 * 255 = 175 and A = 0.561 * 255 = 143.

The `rsPackColorTo8888()` function itself works correctly, but when the found `uchar4` value is returned from the kernel, something really weird happens. The R, G and B value changes to respectively Red * Alpha = 56, Green * Alpha = 56 and Blue * Alpha = 56 where Alpha is 0.561. This means that no value of R, G and B can ever be larger than A = 0.561 * 255.

Setting the output manually, instead of using `rsPackColorTo8888()` yields exact the same behavior. I mean that following code produces the exact same result, which in turn proofs that `rsPackColorTo8888()` is not the problem:

```
if (square(x - centerX) + square(y - centerY) < square(radius)) {
    // Check if current position is transparent, we then need to add the background!)
    if (f4.a == 0) {
        uchar4 temp;
        temp[0] = 175;
        temp[1] = 175;
        temp[2] = 175;
        temp[3] = 143;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

This is the Java-code from which the script is called:

```
@Override
public Bitmap renderParallel(Bitmap input, int backgroundColour, int padding) {
    ResizeUtility resizeUtility = new ResizeUtility();

    // We want to end up with a square Bitmap with some padding applied to it, so we use the
    // the length of the largest dimension (width or height) as the width of our square.
    int dimension = resizeUtility.getLargestDimension(input.getWidth(), input.getHeight()) + 2 * padding;

    Bitmap output = resizeUtility.createSquareBitmapWithPadding(input, padding);
    output.setHasAlpha(true);

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(this.context);

    Allocation inputAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, output);
    Type t = inputAlloc.getType();

    Allocation outputAlloc = Allocation.createTyped(rs, t);

    ScriptC_circle_render circleRenderer = new ScriptC_circle_render(rs);

    circleRenderer.set_centerX(dimension / 2);
    circleRenderer.set_centerY(dimension / 2);
    circleRenderer.set_radius(dimension / 2);
    circleRenderer.set_destinationA(((float) Color.alpha(backgroundColour)) / 255.0f);
    circleRenderer.set_destinationR(((float) Color.red(backgroundColour)) / 255.0f);
    circleRenderer.set_destinationG(((float) Color.green(backgroundColour)) / 255.0f);
    circleRenderer.set_destinationB(((float) Color.blue(backgroundColour)) / 255.0f);

    circleRenderer.forEach_circleRender(inputAlloc, outputAlloc);
    outputAlloc.copyTo(output);

    inputAlloc.destroy();
    outputAlloc.destroy();
    circleRenderer.destroy();
    rs.destroy();

    return output;
}
```

When alpha is set to 255 (or 1.0 as a float), the returned color-values (inside my application's Java-code) are correct.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this really a bug somewhere in the RenderScript-implementation?

Note: I've checked and verified this behavior on a Oneplus 3T (Android 7.1.1), a Nexus 5 (Android 7.1.2), Android-emulator version 7.1.2 and 6.0

Comment: Can you share your java code and what device you are testing on?

Comment: @sakridge Thanks for replying! I've added the Java-code and the devices I used for testing to my post.

Comment: I am not certain, but maybe `fa.a == 0` comparison evaluates to false because `fa.a` is float. If you change to `in.a == 0`, does it  produces same output?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the values with the type:

```
uchar4 temp = rsPackColorTo8888(0.686f, 0.686f, 0.686f, 0.561f);
```

Trying creating a float4 and passing that.

```
float4 newFloat4 = { 0.686, 0.686, 0.686, 0.561 };
uchar4 temp = rsPackColorTo8888(newFloat4);
```